# Standard deviation of a difference of multiple means

Tags: statistics, means, variance

I am currently try to refresh my statistics knowledge and fail at the following basic question:

Given are two vectors $$x'=(x1,x2,x3,..., xk)$$ and $$y'=(y1,y2,y3,...,yk)$$ that contain sampling of two iid random variables.

The difference of the sampling average is:  $$d(x,y) = m(x) - m(y)$$

m(x) and m(y) are realizations of a discrete random variable. It follows d(x,y) is also a realization of a random variable d(X,Y)

**I try to determine the variance of d(X,Y) as a function of the variance var(Xi) and var(Yi)**

Do I need the formula for the variance of sums: $$var(X+Y) = var(X)+var(Y) +2cov(X,Y)$$ and $$1/n * var(Y)$$  and $$ 1/n * var(X)$$ to solve the term?

Thanks! :-)

Comment: please make use of MathJax (LaTeX renderer on this page)...it makes it easier for others to read your question

Comment: I am sorry, I did never use LaTeX before and I am not really familiar with such tools..

Comment: no problem, just check my profile where you can find a quick MathJax tutorial

Comment: You have basically listed the tools one uses. It is not absolutely clear, but it looks as if you are expected to assume the $X_i$ and $Y_j$ are independent.